# Apply Attribute with AttributeTargets = Method to all methods in a class

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

There is an `Attribute` called `DataSourceAttribute` in C#. It needs to be declared on each Method again and again. Is it possible to declare it one time at the class level so that I don't need to repeat myself. If so, how?

In Data Driven UnitTesting, the data source need to be specified with the help of this attribute: `[DataSource (...),...]`. There are about 10-15 such methods, and I do not want to declare the attribute for each method. I'd like to declare it once and have all the methods inherit it from the class level usage.

Comment: please make your question clear

Comment: "Apply Attribute with AttributeTargets = Method to all methods in a class" can any1 explain this ??

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Afterthough](https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought/wiki/Amend-Attributes). It is a framework that applies custom chunks of code, including properties, methods, attributes to your solution post-compile.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to create a custom class attribute that applies the method attribute to all methods in the class.

Here is the MSDN for custom attributes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: DataSourceAttribute can not be inherited so I dont think a custome class attribute is possible..

Comment: You won't want to inherit from the DataSourceAttribute, you'll want to make a new class attribute that applies the DataSourceAttribute to all methods in the class.

Comment: could you please explain with an example?

Comment: how to i explicitly add an attribute to a method from another method..
for example I have a method A and another method B .. here B is data driven.. so how do i add attribute "DataSource" to method B..

Comment: I've created a class level attribute that can create the datasource attribute for the method. I then have a base class that the test class and inherit from that will iterate over all the methods of the class and create a dynamicmethod of each class. The problem is now having to parse the IL generated from each method body. Even if that's possible (I'm sure it is, it would just take a long time to get working..) adding the attribute to the dynamic method isn't clear to me. I think that at this point it's just easier to add the datasource to each method. Sorry.